# As far as I'm understanding

Tags: tense

Is the start of the phrase, 'As far as I'm understanding' correct to show politeness, or should it be 'As far as I understand'?

Comment: Apparently, ***my*** preferred phrasing - ***So** far as I know* - ceased to be the most popular choice over 50 years ago. I guess that just confirms I'm an old fogey!

Comment: "As far as I'm understanding" is an idiom favoured on the Indian subcontinent, where others say "As far as I understand." Compare "I am liking it" with "I like it."

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a little bit off to so say it the first way, so I recommend sticking with "As far as I understand..." which is already quite polite.  You might also go with the slightly more customary "As I understand it, ...."